# Function composition with the Writer monad?

Tags: haskell, function-composition, writer-monad

I'm studying the `Writer` monad and have the following:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Writer String Int
myFunction e1 e2 
   | e1 > e2 = do
      tell ("E1 greater")
      return (e1)
   | otherwise = do
      tell ("E2 greater")
      return (e2)

main = do
-- execWriter :: Writer w a -> w 
   print $ execWriter . myFunction 1 2
```

Error:

```
"Couldn't match type ‘WriterT String Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Int’with ‘a0 -> Writer c0 a1’
  Expected type: a0 -> Writer c0 a1
    Actual type: Writer String Int"
```

Why does this computation error with `.` and not `$`? Perhaps my understanding of function composition is incorrect?

Comment: well the `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` operator expects two functions each taking one argument and the right one `myFunction` here has no argument (or at least not the one) that `execWriter` is expecting.

Comment: You can also define `(.:) = (.) . (.)` and then use, `execWriter .: myFunction $ 1 2`. It is also known as the "owl operator". (`(.:)` is already defined in `Data.Composition` - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Composition.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function composition with `.` means that the resulting composition will receive an argument.

This portion:

```
execWriter . myFunction 1 2
```

Can be written more explicitly like this:

```
(\x -> execWriter (myFunction 1 2 x))
```

Since `myFunction` only takes two arguments, you are getting a compile error.

Had you used `$` in your code, like this:

```
execWriter $ myFunction 1 2
```

The resulting code expanded is equivalent to this:

```
execWriter (myFunction 1 2)
```

Which is valid.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Chad said, this happens because regular function application (without using `$`) has a higher priority than all operators (infix functions), including `.`.

Your example would have worked if you had written it like this:

```
(execWriter . myFunction 1) 2
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(\x -> execWriter (myFunction 1 x)) 2
```

Which then evaluates to:

```
execWriter (myFunction 1 2)
```